# Resultant maximum amplitude and resultant frequency of two sine waves

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

If it is given that
$a \sin(x) + b \cos(y) = c \sin(z)$
then what is $c$ and $z$ in terms of $a, b, x, y$?
Much tackled problem in signal communication problems associated with modulation. With this generalized solution, $c=$ Maximum value of amplitude and $z=$ resultant frequency can easily be measured.

Comment: I'm not sure I am clear on the question.  If there are two vars, x and y, then this looks like a 'wavy blanket' in 3-space.  Is z supposed to be a complex number, such that you get the same 'shape' over the complex plane?

Comment: I thought the point of modulation is that what comes out is not a sine wave. Are you sure the formula you've written has any relevance? Maybe give a reference to some source for this formula so we can see exactly where it comes from.

Comment: It is like 4sin(100)+6cos(75)=a*sin(b) and in that case, what is a and b?